# How do I include scripts required for my plugin within the head tags of the site?

Tags: cakephp, plugins, cakephp-2.1

I'm trying to make a image uploader plugin for CakePHP (yes, I know it's been done before).  It will require javascript and css files that I've put in the `/pluginname/webroot/js/` and `/pluginname/webroot/css/` folders.

I want the user to just be able to include the element wherever they want the uploader to be - but where do I include the javascript and css?

In my layout file, I'm echoing the css and scripts like this:

```
echo $this->fetch('css');
echo $this->fetch('scripts');
```

I've tried adding the plugin's files in the upload.php element (located in pluginname/View/Elements), but the only way I can get it to work is with a straight echo:

```
echo $this->Html->script('/plupload/js/upload.full');
```

When I try to add the 'inline'=>false like this:

```
echo $this->Html->script('/plupload/js/plupload.full', array('inline'=>false));
```

It just doesn't get included.

BUT - my CSS file gets included in the header just fine from the same location by doing this:

```
$this->Html->css('/plupload/js/jquery.queue/css/plupload.queue',
    null, array('inline'=>false));
```

Maybe including them from within the element isn't the way to go - there must be a "norm" for this kind of thing.

[DebugKit](https://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit) (the best CakePHP plugin ever) is just loaded via the bootstrap, and voila - it works - the javascript and css automatically gets put into my .  How does it do it?  Or how should/can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is not only a typo in your question, the doc http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/views.html#using-blocks-for-script-and-css-files uses 'script' instead of 'scripts' for the block:

```
echo $this->fetch('script');
```

Comment: In present context it is `$this->Html->script('PluginName./js/upload.full', ['block' => true]);`